# Attribute sets with specific attribute

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, attribute-set

How can I get a collection with the attribute sets that contain a certain attribute?
I want to be able do to this from a single collection walk (on single select), to avoid loading each attribute set and checking the attributes inside.
I know this seams like standard stuff, but I'm a bit slow these days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        $attributeId = 96;
        $collection  = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('eav_entity_attribute.attribute_id', $attributeId)
            ->addFieldToFilter('eav_entity_type.entity_type_code', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)
            ->join(array('eav_entity_type'=> 'eav/entity_type'), 'eav_entity_type.entity_type_id=main_table.entity_type_id','entity_type_code')
            ->join(array('eav_entity_attribute'=> 'eav/entity_attribute'), 'eav_entity_attribute.attribute_set_id=main_table.attribute_set_id', 'attribute_id');
```

Comment: Works like a charm, nice one!

Comment: Yep. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I found this right before @mageUz wrote the perfect answer. It's fast if you need only the attribute set ids. Maybe someone else needs it.

```
$attributeId = 123;
$setInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
        ->getSetInfo(array($attributeId));
$attributeSetIds = array_keys($setInfo[$attributeId]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it with Magento objects but a direct query would work just as well I guess

```
SELECT  `eav_entity_attribute`.`attribute_set_id` 
FROM  `eav_attribute` ,  `eav_entity_attribute` 
WHERE  `eav_attribute`.`attribute_code` =  'cost'
AND  `eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` =  `eav_entity_attribute`.`attribute_id`
```

Comment: Thanks. I found that table also. I guess I have to write my own resource model in order to use this query. +1, but I don't accept the answer yet. I'm hoping for a `Magento` solution

Comment: Challenge accepted! If I'm home early tonight that is ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get all attribute of particular attribute set.

```
 $data =   Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
        ->setAttributeSetFilter(9) // Add attribute set ID
        ->load();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think you misunderstood the question. I want the other way around. All ATTRIBUTE SETS that contain a certain ATTRIBUTE.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. But I'll try to find magento solution.

Comment: No problem. no inconvenience at all.